# Java extending Map.entry() without generics

Tags: java, generics, interface, hashmap

What I want to do is eventually be able to run this:

```
HashMap<FooClass> foo;
```

However I couldn't manage to implement the `FooClass` here:

I've tried

```
public class FooClass<String, List<String>> extends Map.Entry<String, List<String>>
```

which causes issues with `List<String>`

If I simplify it and try

```
public class FooClass<String, Integer> extends Map.Entry<String, Integer>
```

then I get no interface expected here error at

```
Map.Entry<String, Integer>
```

So if I change it to `Map.Entry<>` then it expects an identifier. What would be the right way of extending `Map.entry`?

Comment: The names declared between `<>` in `class FooClass<String, List<String>>` define **new** _type variables_. They do not refer to existing types.

Comment: Why are you trying to extend `Map.Entry`? Just make a `FooClass` and override `hashCode()` if you need to.

Comment: A class can't "extend" [an interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html).

Comment: @ChrisMartin sorry about that, replace extends with implements, but the logic remains the same

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried to compile these, but usually you don't use a type parameter on the class you declare in these cases:

```
public class FooClass implements Map.Entry<String, List<String>>
```

or

```
public class FooMap extends HashMap<String, List<String>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a guess at what you're trying to do, because it isn't clear to me from your question. But if you're trying to come up with a HashMap implementation for a specific purpose that doesn't expose generic parameters, you can do that by extending a parameterized HashMap.

For example let's say what you're wanting to do is map a name property in your FooClass instances to the instances themselves. You can extend HashMap like this:

```
public class FooClassMap extends HashMap<String, FooClass> { }
```

Then you just instantiate your new implementation, without any of the generics syntax, like this:

```
FooClassMap fooClassMap = new FooClassMap();
```

And use it like this (assuming it has a name property that's initialized in the constructor):

```
FooClass fooClass = new FooClass("fooClassName");
fooClassMap.add(fooClass.getName(), fooClass);
```

I hope that's what you're looking for, sorry if it isn't.

Comment: That's a good point, but I had troubles extending Map.Entry like this: `public class FooClassMap extends HashMap<String, FooClass> {  interface Entry extends Map.Entry<String, FooClass>{} }`. do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that you can write a `HashMap<Foo>` for any *single* argument `Foo`.  `HashMap` expects two type parameters; messing around with `Map.Entry` will not change that.

Comment: isn't there a `typedef` equivalent in Java that exists in C++?